# What's the best way to grab attributes of a particular td in html table?

Tags: python

everybody.
So, I'm trying to write this function as a part of my python course. What it should do is go to a wiki page, parse the table with Greek philosophers there, and return the list of tuples, each containing the name of the philosopher and a link to his wiki page. Below is what I've got:

```
def get_philosophers():
    url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Greek_philosophers"
    philosophers = []

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.status_code == 200:
            return 'Main page error'
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
        table = page.find('table',class_='wikitable')
        trs = table.find_all('tr')

        bigname = ()

        for tr in trs:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            name = tds[0].find('a').get('title')
            link = "https://wikipedia.org" + tds[0].find('a').get('href')
            bigname = (name, link)
        philosophers.append(bigname)
        return len(philosophers)

    except:
        print('Scraping error')
```

I've tried commands via console, they mainly worked; except for the 'for' loop, which returned 'index out of range' error on the `name = tds[0].find('a').get('title')` line, but when earlier I tried same commands not as a loop, but just for one of the elements, they worked alright.

UPD: modified the function:

```
    url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Greek_philosophers"
    philosophers = []

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.status_code == 200:
            return 'Main page error'
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
        table = page.find('table',class_='wikitable')
        trs = table.find_all('tr')
        bigname = ()

        for tr in trs[1:]: #skip the thead tr element
            try:
                tds = tr.find_all('td')
                name = tds[0].find('a').get('title')
                link = "https://wikipedia.org" + tds[0].find('a').get('href')
                bigname = (name, link)
                philosophers.append(bigname)
                # return philosophers
            except:
                print('Loop error')
        return philosophers
    except:
        print('Scraping error')
```

works as intended.

Comment: there is no td in your tr only `<tr>
<th>Name
</th>
<th>Life
</th>
<th>School
</th>
<th class="sortable" style="background:#e3e3e3">Notes
</th></tr>`

Comment: that is only in the first tr that comes from the thead

Comment: that is why your scraping failed. cuz there is no td to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the position of `try` - `except` that created the issue. Try :

```
def get_philosophers():
    url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Greek_philosophers"
    philosophers = []

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.status_code == 200:
        return 'Main page error'
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    table = page.find('table',class_='wikitable')
    trs = table.find_all('tr')
    bigname = ()
    for tr in trs:
        try:
           tds = tr.find_all('td')
           name = tds[0].find('a').get('title')
           link = "https://wikipedia.org" + tds[0].find('a').get('href')
           bigname = (name, link)
           philosophers.append(bigname)
        except:
            pass
    return len(philosophers)
```

Now call it:

```
x = get_philosophers()
print(x)
```

What this does is that, it skips the error causing `tr` while iterating.
Or just delete the first error causer:

```
def get_philosophers():
    url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Greek_philosophers"
    philosophers = []

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if not response.status_code == 200:
            return 'Main page error'
        page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
        table = page.find('table',class_='wikitable')
        trs = table.find_all('tr')

        bigname = ()
        del trs[0] # deletion
        for tr in trs:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            name = tds[0].find('a').get('title')
            link = "https://wikipedia.org" + tds[0].find('a').get('href')
            bigname = (name, link)
            print(bigname)
            philosophers.append(bigname)
        return len(philosophers)

    except:
        print('Scraping error')
```

Comment: Actually, tipped off by your first comment I solved the issue myself before I saw your solution. I mean - thanks a lot!